# How to select check box which generate div[i] during runtime in selenium-java?

Tags: java, selenium

"N" number of check boxes will get created during run time depending on the selection of previous screen..

For below xpath it is "1".

```
//*[@id="chargedashboard"]/div[1]/span[3]/label/span[3]
```

If I want to select 1,9 and 15th checkboxes ,how to write code to select during runtime.

Comment: You need dynamic XPath which contains all checkboxes and checked desired checkboxes by giving numbers. show me your html code so i can give you perfect xpath

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function click(IwebElement e){e.click();} takes webelement and performs click operation on it.
while calling send the dynamic xpath of element to it
You can use selenium-ide or Katalon Recorder for it.
find out dynamic xpath of your prefered checkboxes (use chropath extension or in DevTools Element window right click on desired tag -> copy -> copy XPath).

```
click(Driver.FindElement(". //*[@id="chargedashboard"]/div[1]/span[3]/label/span[3]"));
click(Driver.FindElement(". //*[@id="chargedashboard"]/div[9]/span[3]/label/span[3]"));
click(Driver.FindElement(". //*[@id="chargedashboard"]/div[15]/span[3]/label/span[3]"));
```

it would be helpful in future if you use,

```
IreadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> list;
list = Driver.findElements(By.XPath(". //*[@id="chargedashboard"]/div"))
```

the iterate through it using forEach loop.